# Azure Media Services - encoding 4K UHD video with v3

Tags: azure, video-encoding, azure-media-services

I made a library that encodes video in Azure using v3 API (.NET Core). I successfully made encoding up to FHD.
But then I tried to encode 4k UHD video (based on [How to encode with a custom Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/customize-encoder-presets-how-to) and [H264 Multiple Bitrate 4K](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-mes-preset-h264-multiple-bitrate-4k) articles).
So, here's my code to create this Transform:

```
        private static async Task<Transform> Ensure4kTransformExistsAsync(IAzureMediaServicesClient client,
        string resourceGroupName,
        string accountName)
    {
        H264Layer CreateH264Layer(int bitrate, int width, int height)
        {
            return new H264Layer(
                profile: H264VideoProfile.Auto,
                level: "auto",
                bitrate: bitrate, // Note that the units is in bits per second
                maxBitrate: bitrate,
                //bufferWindow: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),    // this is the default
                width: width.ToString(),
                height: height.ToString(),
                bFrames: 3,
                referenceFrames: 3,
                adaptiveBFrame: true,
                frameRate: "0/1"
            );
        }

        // Does a Transform already exist with the desired name? Assume that an existing Transform with the desired name
        // also uses the same recipe or Preset for processing content.
        Transform transform = await client.Transforms.GetAsync(resourceGroupName, accountName, TRANSFORM_NAME_H264_MULTIPLE_4K_S);

        if (transform != null) return transform;

        // Create a new Transform Outputs array - this defines the set of outputs for the Transform
        TransformOutput[] outputs =
        {
            // Create a new TransformOutput with a custom Standard Encoder Preset
            new TransformOutput(
                new StandardEncoderPreset(
                    codecs: new Codec[]
                    {
                        // Add an AAC Audio layer for the audio encoding
                        new AacAudio(
                            channels: 2,
                            samplingRate: 48000,
                            bitrate: 128000,
                            profile: AacAudioProfile.AacLc
                        ),
                        // Next, add a H264Video for the video encoding
                        new H264Video(
                            // Set the GOP interval to 2 seconds for both H264Layers
                            keyFrameInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                            // Add H264Layers
                            layers: new[]
                            {
                                CreateH264Layer(20000000, 4096, 2304),
                                CreateH264Layer(18000000, 3840, 2160),
                                CreateH264Layer(16000000, 3840, 2160),
                                CreateH264Layer(14000000, 3840, 2160),
                                CreateH264Layer(12000000, 2560, 1440),
                                CreateH264Layer(10000000, 2560, 1440),
                                CreateH264Layer(8000000, 2560, 1440),
                                CreateH264Layer(6000000, 1920, 1080),
                                CreateH264Layer(4700000, 1920, 1080),
                                CreateH264Layer(3400000, 1280, 720),
                                CreateH264Layer(2250000, 960, 540),
                                CreateH264Layer(1000000, 640, 360)
                            }
                        ),
                        // Also generate a set of PNG thumbnails
                        new PngImage(
                            start: "25%",
                            step: "25%",
                            range: "80%",
                            layers: new[]
                            {
                                new PngLayer(
                                    "50%",
                                    "50%"
                                )
                            }
                        )
                    },
                    // Specify the format for the output files - one for video+audio, and another for the thumbnails
                    formats: new Format[]
                    {
                        // Mux the H.264 video and AAC audio into MP4 files, using basename, label, bitrate and extension macros
                        // Note that since you have multiple H264Layers defined above, you have to use a macro that produces unique names per H264Layer
                        // Either {Label} or {Bitrate} should suffice

                        new Mp4Format(
                            "Video-{Basename}-{Label}-{Bitrate}{Extension}"
                        ),
                        new PngFormat(
                            "Thumbnail-{Basename}-{Index}{Extension}"
                        )
                    }
                ),
                OnErrorType.StopProcessingJob,
                Priority.Normal
            )
        };

        const string DESCRIPTION = "Multiple 4k";
        // Create the custom Transform with the outputs defined above
        transform = await client.Transforms.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, accountName, TRANSFORM_NAME_H264_MULTIPLE_4K_S,
            outputs,
            DESCRIPTION);

        return transform;
    }
```

But the job ends up with the following error:

> > Job ended with error: Fatal service error, please contact support.
> >      An error has occurred. Stage: ProcessSubtaskRequest. Code: System.Net.WebException.

And I did use **S3 Media Reserved Unit** for encoding. So, is there any way to make it work?

Comment: As responded in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9155e07b-a57c-4690-bbc6-f4157efeee22/encoding-4k-uhd-video-with-v3, please share details like Job Name, media service account name, region/data center name? You can contact us via amshelp@microsoft.com if you prefer. We will need to look at the logs to determine the cause of the failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting back the solutions to this thread for completeness

1. There was a bug in the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet-tutorials/blob/master/AMSV3Tutorials/UploadEncodeAndStreamFiles/Program.cs) code (RunAsync() method), which resulted in Jobs using an incorrect output Asset. The bug has now been fixed.
2. There was a related bug in error handling that is being addressed